# Present ViewController on top of other programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code which present my viewcontroller **instead** of an existing one:

```
let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(identifier: "me.app.MyFramework")
var storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: frameworkBundle)

var vc = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController() as MyPresenterViewController

viewControllerToPresentIn.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I want to present the viewcontroller **on top** of the other one programmatically,

any ideas?

Comment: This code seems to actually be presenting one view controller on top of another. What do you mean when you say "on top" and how does it differ from "instead"?

Comment: @nkukushkin My view controller contains only a button and this is what I see, I can't see the article that under it

Comment: if you create a new window on e.g. alert-level and add your controller to that, and when you make that key, then it will top of everything on the screen, including the current keyboard as well.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want your modal view controller to be see-though you have to give its view a `clear color` background. And set its `modalPresentationStyle` to `.OverCurrentContext`.

```
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! MyPresenterViewController
vc.view.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext

viewControllerToPresentIn.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I need to be also touchable, meaning that I can press on the view controller behind, is it possible?

Comment: I didn't understood how I can override hittest, it's a method of my UIVIEW meaning self.view.
How can I override it?

Comment: You have to make a subclass. And then change the class of the root view of the controller with button in storyboard.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote an answer with the code I choose to use, thanks for your help!

Comment: When I present it following this advice, I'm unable to see the view behind it. My presented view controller background is opaque or pure black even though I set the background color to clear.

Comment: For anyone who's reading this in the future: If you need the ViewController in the back to receive touch events, then think about adding the new one as a child view controller.

Answer (score 6):

I used the following approach in order to present my view only on the bottom of the other view controller:

```
var presenterStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MiniAppPanel", bundle: frameworkBundle)

var vc = presenterStoryBoard.instantiateInitialViewController() as MiniAppPanelViewController

vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, vc.view.frame.size.height - 120, vc.view.frame.size.width, 120)

publisherViewController.addChildViewController(vc)    
publisherViewController.view.addSubview(vc.view)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using navigationcontroller you can change viewcontrollers as

```
    navigationController?.presentViewController(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but since presenting doesn't bring the view from left or right you'll lose your navigationcontroller