# Each time a button is pressed, trying to present view controller on top of another

Tags: swift

Every time a button is pressed, I am trying to present another view controller on top of it. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929424/present-viewcontroller-on-top-of-other-programmatically), and it works when I press the button for the 1st time. However, when I press the button for the 2nd/3rd/etc. time, the view controller does not appear and the print statement does not print either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func myButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("button pressed")

        var vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myIdentifier") as! secondViewController
        var transparentGrey=UIColor(red: 0.26, green: 0.26, blue: 0.26, alpha: 0.90)
         vc.view.backgroundColor = transparentGrey
         vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**EDIT: The above code works as long as you dismiss the secondViewController correctly after the button was first pressed. I put this code in the secondViewController and it worked for me:**

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: are you correctly dismissing the secondViewController ?  Try once by providing backgroundColor to your secondViewController and then dismiss it

Comment: Glad it helped. :)